# how to read registry values for the particular user

Tags: command-line, registry

Do anyone have read the registry value for the particular user by using command prompt in windows? If anyone have read before by specify the user name please help me how may I get the value by using command-line command. Am trying to read the date and time format value from the registry but I getting different format for the different users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the users's SID you can query the registry for specific user settings. The following will get the `sShortDate` date format value for a user with SID: 123

```
reg query "HKEY_USERS\123\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate
```

To get the SID for a specific user you can use `wmic` to get a list of name, sid pairs for all users of the system:

```
wmic useraccount get name,sid
```

Comment: Hi Christian Hagelid, I have got the SID of the particular user by using wmic but still I couldn't find the registry key for the particular SID. 

Actually in my test machine I have 23 users but I have the registry key's for two users only not for others. What may the cause couldn't get the key's for other users. 

What I have to do in my machine to get the registry keys for other users. Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: I'm not too sure. Are you running the command as an administrator?

Comment: Ya am using command prompt as administrator privilege only and in my test machine I have logged in as administrator, and I have checked with the registry editor to check with those registry I couldn't find any related keys for the users other than administrator.

Comment: Can you see the SID entries for all the 23 accounts under the HKEY_USERS node in the registry?

Comment: Actually no i can only see two users details under HKEY_USERS node.

Comment: Sounds like the other accounts you mentioned aren't actually local accounts

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this in golang and [Christian Hagelid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195679/996129) comment got me unstuck, so thanks!

Here's what it looks like in golang (must run as administrator):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

func main() {
    sid, domain, accType, err := windows.LookupSID("", "testuser")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", sid, domain, accType)

    keyPath := fmt.Sprintf(`%v\Control Panel\International`, sid)    
    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.USERS, keyPath, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("sDecimal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decimal symbol is %s\n", s)
}
```